# heroku file upload in php

Tags: heroku

I'm wondering for long period of time for making an app in facebook with heroku server. Actually my app dynamically generates image via php. But heroku wont allow allow me for image generation. Can some one explain me how to solve it or recommend any other free server like heroku?

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know what your question is, since you didn't post any specifics or code samples, but I'm betting your issue is with Heroku having a read-only filesystem. If you want your app to be able to create/store/manipulate files, you should be using external storage. I use Amazon S3 with Heroku to store images for my Rails apps and it works great. Google "Heroku s3" and you should find a wealth of information.

More info on the filesystem restraints: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/read-only-filesystem